# TFS plug-in is not working for eclipse 2019-09

Tags: plugins, tfs, java-11, eclipse-2019-09

I'm recently migrated to jdk 11 from jdk8. So, i choose eclipse 2019-09 but TFS plug-in is not showing in eclipse market place. so, i tried installing it manually, but some options are not working like viewHistory, comparing based on change sets etc, will the TFS plug-in supports latest eclipse versions?

Comment: You could try looking in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there are any messages, but it doesn't look like this code has been updated since 2018 so it might not be compatible with the current Eclipse release (which is now 2019-12)

Comment: https://twitter.com/jessehouwing/status/1209412953843388416

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this link [Team Explorer Everywhere](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/team-explorer-everywhere) TFS pluging supports:

> Neon (4.6), Mars (4.5), Luna (4.4), Kepler (4.3), Juno (4.2, 3.8)

2019-09 is not in list. Users with eclipse (2019-03) also have problems.

Comment: thank you, do you have any idea, like which IDE works with jdk11 + TFS Plug-in

Comment: No, I cannt say..... I only found a github project for TFS plugin: https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere. Maybe someone`ll adapt it...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere) on Jan 14, 2020. Please refer to [issue 290](https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/issues/290) and/or commit [b8d4e67529a3619d919e7c45f9cb6255ef2b9843](https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/commit/b8d4e67529a3619d919e7c45f9cb6255ef2b9843).

There is no build yet (April 17, 2020), but it is quite easy to build it yourself. There are very good instructions in the readme of the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere).

I cloned the repository and used JDK 8 and Apache Ant 1.9.7 for compilation. I also tried a newer Eclipse version to build against, but that did not work for me. Downloading the given Eclipse 3.5.2 and EGit 2.1.0 made the job.